# implementing a lexer but need help removing comments from input

Tags: c, lexer

I'm implementing a lexer for a simple programming language in c, basically something that reads in tokens and identifies them as symbols, numbers, reserved words, etc. I have this part done and working but I'm having trouble with the step before it lexes the input. Namely I must first find any comments in the input programming code and replaces the comment symbols (which are the same in c) and everything between them with a space. However, when I tried to do this it ends up looking very weird. I'm pretty sure this is because it's been awhile since I've used c and I'm probably getting confused with how it's handling memory or something so any help would be appreciated.

Also I know there is a built in token functionality in c but I am not allowed to use it here in case anyone suggests a fix that uses that.

```
//function to remove comments from input code
    void makeClean(char *clean)
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (clean[i] != '\0' && i < 500)
        {
            if (clean[i] == '/' && clean[i + 1] == '*')
            {
                while ((!(clean[i] == '*' && clean[i + 1] == '/')) && i < 500)
                {
                    clean[i] = ' ';
                    i++;
                }
                clean[i] = ' ';
                clean[i + 1] = ' ';
                i++;
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
    //main
    int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
        char input[500];
        //char *clean = input;
        int i = 0;
        char flag1[9];
        char flag2[9];
        char temp[500];
        while (argv[1][i] != '\0')
        {
            input[i] = argv[1][i];
            i++;
        }
        char *clean = input;
        //getting possible flags
        for (i = 0; i < 17; i++)
        {
            if (i < 8)
                flag1[i] = input[i];
            if (i > 8)
                flag2[i - 9] = input[i];
        }
        flag1[9] = '\0';
        flag2[9] = '\0';
        //flag checks
        if (strcmp(flag1,"--source") == 0 || strcmp(flag2,"--source") == 0)
            printf("source code:\n------------\n%s\n\n",input);
        if (strcmp(flag1,"--clean") == 0 || strcmp(flag2,"--clean") == 0)
        {
            makeClean(clean);
            printf("source code without comments:\n-----------------------------\n%s\n\n",clean);
        }
        //outputting tokens and types
        printf("tokens:\n-------\n\n");
        lex(clean);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: @chux to be honest I'm not even sure why I had that, I was probably tired or something. I got rid of it but I'm still getting the same problem as before

Comment: I'm assuming this must be homework or something, but just to throw up the obvious answer … why not just use `cpp` like C does … ?

Comment: Hint: walk through what values `i` has and what your buffer looks like as you white out `"x/*y*/z"`. Pretty sure you're “getting ahead of yourself.”

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25860644/971127

Comment: @BRFennPocock uh could you elaborate a bit more? That and the line above it should clean up the ending comment symbol or am I wrong?